# Img's doesn't show when placed in "div" element

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, image

I've placed the img in the same folder as code and have spelled it correctly in code, "adHere.jpg", so I know that's not the problem but it might be the format that I put my link in.

So w/out furthur a due, let me show you.

```
 <!--Side Bar Code -->
<div class="sidebar">
  <p><a href="">Home Page</a></p>
  <p><a href="">About Me</a></p>
  <p><a href="">Behind the scenes</a></p>
  <p><a href="">Etc.</a></p>
  <img href="adHere.jpg" width="750" height="450"> 
</div>
```

And here is how my code is in CSS:

```
.sidebar img {border:solid 1px;
      position:relative;
      opacity: 1;}
```

And here's how it renders: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6nsm.png

Answer (score 1):

the source attribute for img is `src` not `href`

Answer (score 1):

The correct attribute for the image source is `src`, not `href`. It should be:

```
<img src="adHere.jpg" width="750" height="450">
```

Comment: Oh! I thought href was used every single time there was a link; guess not. Lol, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 <!--Side Bar Code -->
<div class="sidebar">
  <p><a href="">Home Page</a></p>
  <p><a href="">About Me</a></p>
  <p><a href="">Behind the scenes</a></p>
  <p><a href="">Etc.</a></p>
  <img src="adHere.jpg" width="750" height="450"> 
</div>
```

CSS can stay the same.